# Can I use the same certificate on another server?

Tags: ssl

I have an Ubuntu server 14.04 running Apache with FQDN like example.com.

My website example.com has a valid certificate with common name like *.example.com.

Can I use the same certificate on test.example.com domain or test-example.com?

And also I want to use a load balancer for these two servers. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a certificate on multiple servers, under two conditions.  The first being that the sites are using the same hostname, the second being you've purchased a wildcard certificate which entitles you to use any subdomain *.example.com.

HAProxy is an example of a load balancer that would work.  You'll need to consider how you intend on handling the SSL traffic.  If you don't plan on using a caching server between your load balancer and web servers you can choose to pass the ssl traffic, or terminate it at your load balancer.  If you plan on caching, you will need to terminate ssl at your load balancer.  The benefit of this is your sites actually listen non-ssl behind your balancer and your balancer will actually handle the ssl certs.  So you only need to install the ssl on your balancer.

Comment: That means i should have another server with haproxy installed? 
Guide me to tutorials please..

Comment: How about buying a load balancer from f5 or citrix ?

Comment: I've not used f5 or citrix, but I assume they would work.  Here is a link for ssl termination using HAProxy.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-ssl-termination-with-haproxy-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: But remember that you will have to install the private key on both servers.  That means that the private key isn't really that private anymore - it's shared.  It's down to your security policies really.